# ui:repeatで作成したテーブル行について、f:ajax「追加」ボタン押下で行追加

Tags: ajax, jsf

ui:repeatで作成したテーブル行について、行追加を行いたいのですが、
とすると、
行は追加されますが、テーブル全体が再描画されるため、入力中の値が消えてしまいます。
※テーブルはjqueryのdatatableを使用しています。

MnagedBeanでリストに行を追加し、HTML上のテーブルに行追加のみを行い、
ほかの行は変更再描画させないようにするには、どのように実現できるのでしょうか。
どうしてもわからず困っています。
ご教授頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: ソースコードを載せることは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score -1):

見てくださってありがとうございます。すみません、お願いいたします。

```
<table jsf:id="tableid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>AAA</th>
            <th>BBB</th>
            <th>CCC</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody jsf:id="tbodyid">
        <ui:repeat id="repeatid" varStatus="sts" var="record" value="#{XXXXBean.dataList}" >
            <tr jsf:id="trid">
                <td>
                    <input type="text"   jsf:value="#{record.aaa}"    jsf:id="recordaaa" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text"   jsf:value="#{record.bbb}"    jsf:id="recordbbb" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text"   jsf:value="#{record.ccc}"    jsf:id="recordccc" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ui:repeat>
    </tbody>
</table>

<f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{XXXXBean.addRow}" render="tbodyid" >
    <h:commandButton id="addbtn" value="addbtn"/>
</f:ajax>
```

****XXXXBean.java***********************************************************************

```
@Named("XXXXBean")
@SessionScoped
public class XXXXBean extends BaseBean {
    private List<dataListBean> dataList = null;

    //初期表示処理
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //一行だけ追加しておく
        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        dataList.add(new dataListBean());
        dataList.get(0).setAaa(1);
        dataList.get(0).setBbb(1);
        dataList.get(0).setCcc(1);
    }

    //行追加
    public void addRow() {
        dataList.add(new dataListBean());
    }

    public List<dataListBean> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }

    public void setDataList(List<dataListBean> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }
}
```

****dataListBean.java***********************************************************************

```
public class dataListBean {
    private int aaa;
    private int bbb;
    private int ccc;

    public int getAaa() {
        return aaa;
    }
    public void setAaa(int aaa) {
        this.aaa = aaa;
    }
    public int getBbb() {
        return bbb;
    }
    public void setBbb(int bbb) {
        this.bbb = bbb;
    }
    public int getCcc() {
        return ccc;
    }
    public void setCcc(int ccc) {
        this.ccc = ccc;
    }
}
```

Comment: これは質問に対する回答でしょうか？

Comment: 質問への内容の追加は、質問の編集で行えます。
意図せずアカウントが分かれてしまった場合は[「間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)をご覧下さい。